# jQuery - Executing code when a key is pressed and reverting it back to normal when it's released

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, triggers

The idea is to chain normal keys with modifier keys if they happen to be pressed down. <kbd>c</kbd> versus <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>

The following works:

```
var inc = 10;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 16: // shift
            inc = 100;

            break;

        case 17: // ctrl
            inc = 1;

            break;
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function() {
    inc = 10;
});
```

The variable is set to the respective value when the key is down and it goes back to normal when it's released. But I'm wondering if:

A - You can just wait for the first function to finish, and then execute the code that returns it to normal

B - If there's some kind of built-in way to just revert it back to its original value without manually setting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key is used as a modifier, don't look for it's keycode. Instead, use the `ctrlKey` or `shiftKey` properties of the event. Try this:

```js
var inc = 10;
$('input').val(inc);
  
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    inc = 100;
  } else if (e.ctrlKey) {
    inc = 1;
  }
  
  $('input').val(inc);
});

$(document).keyup(function() {
  inc = 10;
  
  $('input').val(inc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

To answer your questions:

> A - You can just wait for the first function to finish, and then execute the code that returns it to normal
>
> B - If there's some kind of built-in way to just revert it back to its original value without manually setting it

The answer to both is no. The pattern you're using is the best method.

Comment: [This](http://joeydehnert.com/2014/04/06/9-development-practices-that-helped-me-write-more-manageable-and-efficient-javascript-and-jquery/) blogpost says you can "cache selectors" and that it works for mouse events, what's the difference?

Comment: That link goes to a 404

Comment: Refresh the page once and the article will load. I dunno, ask him why

Comment: So it does - very odd. As for caching selectors - that's about holding the jQuery object in memory. It has nothing to do with event handlers